# Mock on the NamedParameterJdbcTemplate or JbdcTemplate ?

Tags: java

I have a problem with mock JbdcTemplate method queryForList .
I don't know which class I should mock: NamedParameterJdbcTemplate or JbdcTemplate ? 
I get error:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: SQL must not be null

What's wrong in code below ?

My code:

```
// Static class/method
public class MyManager{
    ...
    public static NamedParameterJdbcTemplate getInstance(JdbcOperations jdbcOperation){
        ...
    return namedParameterJdbcTemplate;     
    }
}

// DAO class
@Repository
public class SomeDAOImpl{
    ...
    @Resource
    JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate

    public Something someMethod(){
        List<Map<String,Object>> sth = MyManager.getInstance(jdbcTemplate).queryForList(sql.toString(), params );
        ...
    }
}

// Test class
public class MyDAOTest{

    @InjectMock
    SomeDAOImpl someDAO;

    @Mock
    JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplateMock;

    @Before
    public void setUp(){    
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    public void myTest(){
        ... 
        List<Map<String,Object>> sth = new ArrayList<Map<String,Object>>();
    Map<String,Object> maps = new HashMap<String,Object>();
    rows.add(maps);

        when(MyManager.getInstance(jdbcTemplateMock).queryForList(any(String.class), any(SqlParameterSource.class))).thenReturn(sth);


    }


}
```

Comment: Your getInstance() is returning a new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate or something related to the mock you used as parameter?

Comment: getInstance() return a new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate

Comment: What is the goal of the `MyManager.getInstance(jdbcTemplate)` call exactly? Right now the problem is that you can't just inject the JdbcTemplate into your Dao because it's not used directly, it's only being used as a parameter to call that `MyManager.getInstance(jdbcTemplate)` which is a static method so you won't be able to mock it either unless you use tools like PowerMock (I tend to consider having to rely on PowerMock a "code-smell", an indication of flawed design).